# Serve very simple static website from dropbox

Tags: nginx, web-server, dropbox

I'm setting my son up so he can manage his simple website by editing a file on dropbox.

My nginx config looks like this:---

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name         name.com *.name.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12345678/index.html;
        }
}
```

This works fine for serving the `index.html` file. The problem is if he puts an `img` tag in the index.html file that points to a `jpeg` in the same directory as his index.html file on dropbox. it doesn't get picked up. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Break it up into two location blocks. One so that you can be served images (and all other assets) in the root directory, but also telling it to serve images by rewriting it and then proxy passing it. And the other block for serving the index file in the root.

Not tested, but should work.

```
location / {
   proxy_pass https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12345678/index.html;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|css|js) {
   rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12345678/;
}
```

Comment: This gives an error: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" may not have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location,...

Comment: Whoopsie, forgot that proxy_pass needed a URI part. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, but still giving the same error.

Comment: Very strange -- quite confused as that should be working.